# How to check if a cell value is Chinese text in Excel

Tags: vba, excel-formula, unicode, character-encoding, chinese-locale

I have a list of cells which contain the first name of users: `Amy`, `Jim`, `梅`, `明`, `ธนกาญจน์`, `Андрей`, etc. From the name, I would like to determine if a user is Chinese.

Does anyone know if there is any formula or VBA method to determine this?

Comment: Is 弗里茨 a chinese name :-) This sounds like an ambiguos problem ;-)

Comment: @Storax Let‘s assume it is a chinese name here

Comment: I am just saying :-) Let's see if someone really knows something ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is to check based on Chinese text I would prefer using `AscW` function like below

```
Function DetectChineseText(cel As Range) As Boolean
DetectChineseText = True
For i = 1 To Len(cel.Value)
  MidChar = Mid(cel.Value, i, 1)
  If Not (AscW(MidChar) >= 19968 And AscW(MidChar) <= 25343) Then
    DetectChineseText = False
    Exit For
  End If
Next i
End Function
```

But as per this [link](https://www.quora.com/How-much-of-Unicode-is-devoted-to-Chinese-characters/answer/Uri-Granta-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%94) there are 89,602 codepoints assigned in Unicode character set for chinese characters we need to mention every range we needed to detect in the data. For now I just used only one range (19968 to 25343) as per a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_Unified_Ideographs,_part_1_of_4).

You could add the range as per your requirement.

Comment: Ok, then the name in my comment although thought as a joke would give a chinese name then, right?

Comment: Yes since it is in chinese text as the question title says

Comment: Ok, I always thought Fitz is not a chinese first name. But in the other hand, you are right, the title is asking for chinese text. But, then again, in the post it says _From the name, I would like to determine if a user is Chinese_. So, at the end, just an ambiguos problem.

Comment: In that case we may need a Chinese Name database to check